# Where did Allah say in the Qu'ran and hadith that He is moral?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah

I haven’t found a single verse in the Quran where Allah is clearly saying that he is moral.

Where did Allah say in the Qu'ran and hadith that He is moral?

Comment: Presumably because moral is not an Arabic word. Allah has said multiple times he is the Most Just "Is not Allah the most just of judges?" (95:8) and that He is the most merciful "The Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful," (1:3). Being moral is nothing but being just and being merciful.

Comment: And Allah said in a hadith qudsi: "I have forbidden dhulm (oppression) for Myself, and I have made it forbidden amongst you, so do not oppress one another." (Sahih Muslim) And Allah says: "Allah is not ever unjust to His servants" (8:51)

Answer (score 0):

It is because moral is a human code derived from Allah and the advice of His Spirit given to us. Allah is the measure, not the subject to be measured.

Answer (score 0):

The eco system (human microbiome) of our body has negative psychological impact as all microbiome are not the same. They need the environments, space and resources provided by the human body to survive.
So, every human being has a fear of unknown all the time, if not, at least of death. The negative psychology of our eco system makes us feel inferior. That’s why in every difficulty, at first, we assume the worst scenario of the situation and start preparing for the worse effects. But often, we feel helplessness.

At this point, A Momin (believer) thinks that if I can’t do that then Allah will do it for me. That’s why, we experience that at once, thing are getting right, even sometimes without any effort. This is the point, where our negative psychology turns into positive ones that there is Allah Subhan Tallah who save everyone in his helplessness. ****Because, Allah is المقتدر (Al-Muqtadir: the All powerful who deliver a suitable measure of all things. He has absolute strength, power, and mastery. Nothing is beyond his power.)****

And if things didn’t get right on account of Allah hikmah then we find the word of يوم دين (The day of judgment) in Quran again and again. AS we often said spontaneously or out of anger that “I will see you on the day of Judgment.” Think for a moment, the word يوم دين contains such a high positivity and satisfaction for us.

Similarly, if we have to give equal attention to all our worldly and spiritual matters. Are we able to do justice? No, because its only Allah Subhan Tallah’s quality who gives individual attention to every human being. **As only Allah is عدل (Al Adl: the one who rectifies and sets matters straight in a just and equitable manner).**

This is like how, if a person claims that everything is in my control. You feel bad. For example, If I said that everything related to my brother is in my control. You naturally feel repulsiveness about my claim or consider me an arrogant person as you know that it’s only Allah’s attribute, who has control of everything. This is the morality Allah has placed in all of us. Because Allah is all love and wants us to love His creatures. That’s why, we feel love and sympathy for other on the basis of His attribute, He has placed in us. However, we don’t have perfect love like Allah Subhan Tallah and thats the reason, when someone is claiming Allah’s morality, we feel natural resistance inside our ecosystem.